# Vba code to paste the selected data in to another range started from particular column

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing the problem of pasting data in my vba code mentioned below :

```
Range("B:AK").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("AN:BW").Paste
```

I need to copy the data with Range starting from column B to Column AK and paste it into columns starting from AN to BW. But I am getting error 1004. Kindly help me with the updated version of the code. and columns belong to the same worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy >> Paste is a 1-line command:

```
Range("B:AK").Copy Range("AN:BW")
```

---

**Edit 1:**

```
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCell As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change to your sheet's name
    ' safest way to get the last row with data in column "B:AK"

    Set LastCell = .Columns("B:AK").Find(What:="*", Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not LastCell Is Nothing Then
        LastRow = LastCell.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "Error! worksheet is empty", vbCritical
        End
    End If

    .Range("B2:AK" & LastRow).Copy .Range("AN2")
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, @Shai Rado, but I want it from 2nd row because in a first row my headers are being placed so If I update the code like Range("B2: AK").Copy Range("AN2: BW") So It gives error, Kindly suggest me

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Range("B:AK").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("AN").Select
Activesheet.Paste
```

If it doesn't work, try adding a row number to AN, like "AN1"

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
Range("$B$2:$AK$1048576").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("AN2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Let me know if it helps.